# Laravel reset daily & monthly quota usages based on a subscribed_at datetime column

Tags: php, sql, laravel, php-carbon

I've been building a feature in my Laravel project called a "Domain API", effectively it's a wrapper around making requests to some system with configurable URL, method and a `quota_limit_monthly` (int) column and a `quota_limit_monthly_max_usage` (int) column.

Each request made through the `DomainApi` model creates a log on a new model called `DomainApiLog`.

I have a `subscribed_at` datetime column on my `DomainApi` model, and the idea is that when creating a new api through my front-end GUI, I can, for instance, set the date I subscribed to the API along with a daily & monthly maximum number of requests I'd like to use along with a percentage of those maximums.

The issue I face is in resetting these limits on the next day, available month, my `DomainApi` model has this appended attribute I created that gives me, as a percentage, the number of requests I've made within the past month:

```php
/**
  * Count the number of times we've made a request to this api in the past month
  */
 public function getMonthlyRequestCountAttribute()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(DomainApiLog::class)
                 ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonths(1))
                 ->count();
 }

/**
  * Get a percentage of the monthly usage quota
  */
 public function getMonthlyUsageQuotaPercentAttribute()
 {
     if (!$this->quota_limit_monthly || !$this->quota_limit_monthly_max_usage) {
         return 0;
     }

     $limit = $this->quota_limit_monthly;
     $percentLimit = $this->quota_limit_monthly_max_usage;

     if ($percentLimit >= 100) {
         return 0;
     }

     if ($percentLimit < 10) {
         $percent = floatval("0.0$percentLimit");
     } else {
         $percent = floatval("0.$percentLimit");
     }

     $notAllowedToUse = $limit - ($limit * $percent);
     $allowedUsage = round($limit - $notAllowedToUse);

     return round(($this->monthly_request_count / $allowedUsage) * 100);
 }
```

I'm using the `created_at` column to get all my logs in the past month, but once the limit has been reached, let's say I've used the entire quota for a period, then the next day might only give me back a few requests.

Would I need to set up a cron to effectively figure out how many logs to delete?

Struggling with the best approach here.

Comment: Create a table with log as log_periods 
Id, name date_from , date_to

give relations to  DomainApiLog table

Comment: @Shibon would you be able to expand beyond this? I already have a log table as discussed called `DomainApiLog`, which, has a `created_at` and a `request_made_at` datetime column. your answer is effectively what I've. already got, not, what I need to now do